# Using Karma's global installation on my existing project

Tags: node.js, karma-runner

I have installed Karma (global scope) and karma-cli (global scope).
I want to use this global karma to my existing project.

```
which node => /usr/local/bin/node
which karma => /usr/local/bin/karma
```

So, when I'm in my js'folde, I use

```
karma init my.conf.js
```

and the message is:

> Cannot find local Karma!   Please install karma by `npm install karma
>   --save-dev`.

Why I cannot use global Karma on my project, but I must install it locally?

Answer (score 0):

You can use globally installed Karma. Check that **NODE_PATH** contains path to installed `karma` (or `karma.cmd` on Windows).